# Impossible to Write with swift firestore

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore

I would like to know why my download is doing nothing when I press "download invoice" witch French traduction of "télécharger la facture". When I use debugger to know what happen it show me that the file is correctly recover but nothing is written on the iPhone. I already tested on real device and the simulator and the result is the same nothing happen.

Has my debugger said it pass throught this piece of code and then it jump into the end of of the func.

This is my following function for downloading :

```
func downloadInvoice(forSolde solde: Solde) async throws -> URL? {
        let filename = solde.facture
        let soldeCollection = Firestore.firestore().collection("solde")
        
        // Obtenez le chemin du dossier Documents de l'application
        guard let documentsURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first else {
            throw NSError(domain: "AppError", code: 1001, userInfo: ["message": "Erreur lors de la récupération du chemin du dossier Documents"])
        }
        let fileURL = documentsURL.appendingPathComponent(filename)
        
        // Récupération du document depuis Firestore
        let document = try await soldeCollection.document(solde.id).getDocument()
        guard let documentData = document.data(),
              let proprietaireUID = documentData["proprietaire"] as? String else {
            throw NSError(domain: "AppError", code: 1002, userInfo: ["message": "Impossible de trouver le champ proprietaire dans le document"])
        }
        
        // Récupération du fichier depuis Firebase Storage
        return try await withCheckedThrowingContinuation { continuation in
            let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference().child("invoices/\(proprietaireUID)/\(solde.id)/\(filename)")
            storageRef.write(toFile: fileURL) { url, error in
                if let error = error {
                    continuation.resume(throwing: error)
                } else if let url = url {
                    continuation.resume(returning: url)
                } else {
                    continuation.resume(throwing: NSError(domain: "AppError", code: 1003, userInfo: ["message": "Erreur inconnue lors du téléchargement"]))
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

It jump to this piece of code :

```
continuation.resume(returning: url)
```

And then the end.

This is my full class if it help to understand properly :

```
import SwiftUI
import QuickLook
import FirebaseStorage
import Firebase

struct AdminUsersToPaid: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var viewModel: AuthViewModel
    @StateObject var adminUserToPaid = AdminUserToPaidModel()
    @State private var soldes: [Solde] = []
    
    @State private var isShowingToast = false
    @State private var toastMessage = ""
    @State private var fileToPreview: URL?
    
    var body: some View {
        content.onAppear{
            Task{
                await adminUserToPaid.fetchSoldeData()
                soldes = adminUserToPaid.soldeList
            }
        }.toast(isShowing: $isShowingToast, text: Text(toastMessage))
            .background(
                QLPreviewControllerRepresentation(fileURL: $fileToPreview)
            )
    }
    
    var content: some View{
        VStack{
            HStack{
                Text("Utilisateur à payer")
                    .font(.system(size: 24).bold())
                Spacer()
                Image(systemName: "eurosign")
                    .font(.system(size: 32))
                    .foregroundColor(.black)
            }.padding()
            Spacer()
            List(soldes){ solde in
                
                HStack{
                    VStack{
                        Text("Nom Complet").font(.system(size: 14)).multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                        Text("\(solde.proprietaire)").padding(.top,5).font(.system(size: 12)).foregroundColor(.gray).multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                    }
                    Spacer()
                    VStack{
                        Text("Date de la demande").font(.system(size: 14)).multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                        Text("\(formatDate(solde.date))").padding(.top,5).font(.system(size: 12)).foregroundColor(.gray).multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                    }
                    Spacer()
                    VStack{
                        Text("Etat de la demande").font(.system(size: 14)).multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                        Text("\(solde.etat)").padding(.top,5).font(.system(size: 12)).foregroundColor(.gray).multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                    }
                    Spacer()
                    VStack{
                        Text("Total du solde").font(.system(size: 14)).multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                        Text("\(solde.total)").padding(.top,5).font(.system(size: 12)).foregroundColor(.gray).multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                    }
                    Spacer()
                    Button {
                        Task{
                            try await downloadInvoice(forSolde: solde)
                        }
                            } label: {
                                Text("Voir la facture").multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                            }
                }
            }
            NavigationLink {
                AdminDashboard().navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
            } label: {
                HStack(spacing: 3){
                    Text("Retour à la page")
                    Text("Principale").fontWeight(.bold)
                }.font(.system(size: 14))
            }
        }
    }
}

struct QLPreviewControllerRepresentation: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    typealias UIViewControllerType = QLPreviewController
    @Binding var fileURL: URL?
    
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> QLPreviewController {
        let controller = QLPreviewController()
        controller.dataSource = context.coordinator
        return controller
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: QLPreviewController, context: Context) {
        uiViewController.reloadData()
    }
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }
    
    class Coordinator: NSObject, QLPreviewControllerDataSource{
        let parent: QLPreviewControllerRepresentation
        
        init(_ parent: QLPreviewControllerRepresentation) {
            self.parent = parent
        }
        
        func numberOfPreviewItems(in controller: QLPreviewController) -> Int {
            return parent.fileURL != nil ? 1 : 0
        }
        
        func previewController(_ controller: QLPreviewController, previewItemAt index: Int) -> QLPreviewItem {
            guard let url = parent.fileURL else{
                fatalError("L'url devrait être à jour")
            }
            return url as QLPreviewItem
        }
    }
}


extension AdminUsersToPaid {
    func downloadInvoice(forSolde solde: Solde) async throws -> URL? {
        let filename = solde.facture
        let soldeCollection = Firestore.firestore().collection("solde")
        
        // Obtenez le chemin du dossier Documents de l'application
        guard let documentsURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first else {
            throw NSError(domain: "AppError", code: 1001, userInfo: ["message": "Erreur lors de la récupération du chemin du dossier Documents"])
        }
        let fileURL = documentsURL.appendingPathComponent(filename)
        
        // Récupération du document depuis Firestore
        let document = try await soldeCollection.document(solde.id).getDocument()
        guard let documentData = document.data(),
              let proprietaireUID = documentData["proprietaire"] as? String else {
            throw NSError(domain: "AppError", code: 1002, userInfo: ["message": "Impossible de trouver le champ proprietaire dans le document"])
        }
        
        // Récupération du fichier depuis Firebase Storage
        return try await withCheckedThrowingContinuation { continuation in
            let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference().child("invoices/\(proprietaireUID)/\(solde.id)/\(filename)")
            storageRef.write(toFile: fileURL) { url, error in
                if let error = error {
                    continuation.resume(throwing: error)
                } else if let url = url {
                    continuation.resume(returning: url)
                } else {
                    continuation.resume(throwing: NSError(domain: "AppError", code: 1003, userInfo: ["message": "Erreur inconnue lors du téléchargement"]))
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

private func formatDate(_ date: Date) -> String {
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"
    return dateFormatter.string(from: date)
}

struct AdminUsersToPaid_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        AdminUsersToPaid()
    }
}
```

Many thanks to that 2 day that this problem occur...
I'm new if somebody can explain why the code is doing that...
Just to inform you the download works perfectly for kotlin version so my firestore rules works perfectly :)

Comment: Why did you modify the code above ?

Answer (score 0):

Okay I just modified this piece of code to download and receive files from firestore :

```html
import SwiftUI
import QuickLook
import FirebaseStorage
import Firebase

struct AdminUsersToPaid: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var viewModel: AuthViewModel
    @StateObject var adminUserToPaid = AdminUserToPaidModel()
    @State private var soldes: [Solde] = []
    
    @State private var isShowingToast = false
    @State private var toastMessage = ""
    @State private var fileToPreview: URL?
    
    var body: some View {
        content.onAppear{
            Task{
                await adminUserToPaid.fetchSoldeData()
                soldes = adminUserToPaid.soldeList
            }
        }.toast(isShowing: $isShowingToast, text: Text(toastMessage))
            .background(
                QLPreviewControllerRepresentation(fileURL: $fileToPreview)
            )
    }
    
    var content: some View{
        VStack{
            HStack{
                Text("Utilisateur à payer")
                    .font(.system(size: 24).bold())
                Spacer()
                Image(systemName: "eurosign")
                    .font(.system(size: 32))
                    .foregroundColor(.black)
            }.padding()
            Spacer()
            List(soldes){ solde in
                
                HStack{
                    VStack{
                        Text("Nom Complet").font(.system(size: 14)).multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                        Text("\(solde.proprietaire)").padding(.top,5).font(.system(size: 12)).foregroundColor(.gray).multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                    }
                    Spacer()
                    VStack{
                        Text("Date de la demande").font(.system(size: 14)).multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                        Text("\(formatDate(solde.date))").padding(.top,5).font(.system(size: 12)).foregroundColor(.gray).multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                    }
                    Spacer()
                    VStack{
                        Text("Etat de la demande").font(.system(size: 14)).multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                        Text("\(solde.etat)").padding(.top,5).font(.system(size: 12)).foregroundColor(.gray).multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                    }
                    Spacer()
                    VStack{
                        Text("Total du solde").font(.system(size: 14)).multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                        Text("\(solde.total)").padding(.top,5).font(.system(size: 12)).foregroundColor(.gray).multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                    }
                    Spacer()
                    Button {
                        Task{
                            try await downloadInvoice(forSolde: solde)
                        }
                            } label: {
                                Text("Voir la facture").multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                            }
                }
            }
            NavigationLink {
                AdminDashboard().navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
            } label: {
                HStack(spacing: 3){
                    Text("Retour à la page")
                    Text("Principale").fontWeight(.bold)
                }.font(.system(size: 14))
            }
        }
    }
}

struct QLPreviewControllerRepresentation: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    typealias UIViewControllerType = QLPreviewController
    @Binding var fileURL: URL?
    
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> QLPreviewController {
        let controller = QLPreviewController()
        controller.dataSource = context.coordinator
        return controller
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: QLPreviewController, context: Context) {
        uiViewController.reloadData()
    }
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }
    
    class Coordinator: NSObject, QLPreviewControllerDataSource{
        let parent: QLPreviewControllerRepresentation
        
        init(_ parent: QLPreviewControllerRepresentation) {
            self.parent = parent
        }
        
        func numberOfPreviewItems(in controller: QLPreviewController) -> Int {
            return parent.fileURL != nil ? 1 : 0
        }
        
        func previewController(_ controller: QLPreviewController, previewItemAt index: Int) -> QLPreviewItem {
            guard let url = parent.fileURL else{
                fatalError("L'url devrait être à jour")
            }
            return url as QLPreviewItem
        }
    }
}


extension AdminUsersToPaid {
    
    func downloadInvoice(forSolde solde: Solde) async {
        do {
            if let url = try await fetchInvoice(forSolde: solde) {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.fileToPreview = url
                    shareFile(at: url)
                }
            }
        } catch {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.isShowingToast = true
                self.toastMessage = "Une erreur s'est produite lors du téléchargement de la facture: \(error.localizedDescription)"
            }
        }
    }
    
    
    func fetchInvoice(forSolde solde: Solde) async throws -> URL? {
        let filename = solde.facture
        let soldeCollection = Firestore.firestore().collection("solde")
        
        // Obtenez le chemin du dossier Documents de l'application
        guard let documentsURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first else {
            throw NSError(domain: "AppError", code: 1001, userInfo: ["message": "Erreur lors de la récupération du chemin du dossier Documents"])
        }
        let fileURL = documentsURL.appendingPathComponent(filename)
        
        // Récupération du document depuis Firestore
        let document = try await soldeCollection.document(solde.id).getDocument()
        guard let documentData = document.data(),
              let proprietaireUID = documentData["proprietaire"] as? String else {
            throw NSError(domain: "AppError", code: 1002, userInfo: ["message": "Impossible de trouver le champ proprietaire dans le document"])
        }
        
        // Récupération du fichier depuis Firebase Storage
        return try await withCheckedThrowingContinuation { continuation in
            let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference().child("invoices/\(proprietaireUID)/\(solde.id)/\(filename)")
            storageRef.write(toFile: fileURL) { url, error in
                if let error = error {
                    continuation.resume(throwing: error)
                } else if let url = url {
                    print("je suis là")
                    continuation.resume(returning: url)
                } else {
                    continuation.resume(throwing: NSError(domain: "AppError", code: 1003, userInfo: ["message": "Erreur inconnue lors du téléchargement"]))
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    func shareFile(at url: URL) {
        let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [url], applicationActivities: nil)
        if let rootVC = UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.rootViewController {
            rootVC.present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
}

private func formatDate(_ date: Date) -> String {
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"
    return dateFormatter.string(from: date)
}

struct AdminUsersToPaid_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        AdminUsersToPaid()
    }
}
```